# How to manage uploaded files in Tomcat Server?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

I am uploading and saving the audio files in the Tomcat server. I would like to know if their is any limit for saving the uploaded files in the server.

Can anyone please let me know some details to manage those files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disk size would be the size limit to upload. If you are using Linux mount another disk into the upload directory path which will help you to manage files.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. So, you are saying that we don't experience any issue with the Tomcat server or in the performance of the server even though if we upload gig's of data.

Comment: As long as you manage the disk space it should not be an issue. I am still shooting in the dark by assuming your traffic and file sizes to be moderate.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how the files got to your the host running the server, the disk space limit (if there is any quota for the user of the process running the server) is that limit.